# Query index by row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on a project http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~cziegler/BX/ and I want to suggest similar book based on what other users liked (user-based collaborative filtering).

I wanted to query pivot table which failed for memory overflow, so I've grouped my dataset instead. The dataset contains columns user-id, isbn, book-title, book-author, ..., book-rating.

I've tried:

```
#data_p = pd.pivot_table(q_books, values='Book-Rating', index='User-ID', columns='Book-Title') #memory overflow
data_p = q_data.groupby(['User-ID', 'Book-Title'])['Book-Rating'].mean().to_frame()
# For pivot table
def recommend(book_title, min_count):
    print("For book ({})".format(book_title))
    print("- Top 10 books recommended based on Pearsons'R correlation - ")
    i = int(data.index[data['Book-Title'] == book_title][0])
    target = data_p[i]
    similar_to_target = data_p.corrwith(book_title)
    corr_target = pd.DataFrame(similar_to_target, columns = ['PearsonR'])
    corr_target.dropna(inplace = True)
    corr_target = corr_target.sort_values('PearsonR', ascending = False)
    corr_target.index = corr_target.index.map(int)
    corr_target = corr_target.join(data).join(book_rating)[['PearsonR', 'Book-Title', 'count', 'mean']]
    print(corr_target[corr_target['count']>min_count][:10].to_string(index=False))
recommend("The Fellowship of the Ring (The Lord of the Rings, Part 1)", 0)
```

which raises

> KeyError: 50043

I assume the problem are these 3 lines:

```
i = int(data.index[data['Book-Title'] == book_title][0])
target = data_p[i]
similar_to_target = data_p.corrwith(book_title)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of ```i```, what is the value of ```data_p.keys()```

Comment: what's "data" stand for in your code? i = int(data.index[data['Book-Title'] == book_title][0]). It should be data_p, isn't it?

Comment: @LazyCoder The value i=50043. I don't see data_p.keys() in my code.

Comment: I was asking you to print data_p.keys() and let me know IF 50043 was indeed a key in it.

Comment: @SUN I believe that's correct. I want to return an index of a book title and since the index isn't reset, I should be able to take it for further use or not?

Comment: @LazyCoder I printed data_p.keys() and it returned: Index(['Score'], dtype='object'). Score = Book-Rating, I've just renamed the column.

Comment: @Stanislav, you are working on user based recommendation and you want book recommendations for user. Your recommendation function should ask for user ID and not Book-Title.  You should not group (user Id, Book-Title), I believe it always be unique, each user should have one rating per book.

Comment: "data" is data frame which already populated with some data, is that correct?